# How to insert and update all the data from datagridview to sql datatable

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

I want to type all the data in a datagridview and insert into SQL datatable or if the data exist it should update the data in SQL datatable using the datagridview.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows

        If row.IsNewRow = False Then

            sqlSTR = "SELECT ID, Name, Abbrev FROM TBL_Stream WHERE (Name = '" & row.Cells(0).Value & "')"
            ExecuteSQLQuery(sqlSTR)

            If sqlDT.Rows.Count > 0 Then

                sqlSTR = "UPDATE TBL_Stream SET Name ='" & row.Cells(0).Value & "', Abbrev ='" & row.Cells(1).Value & "' WHERE (Name ='" & row.Cells(0).Value & "')"
                ExecuteSQLQuery(sqlSTR)

                GetGrid()
                MsgBox("Record Updated", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Update")

            Else

                sqlSTR = "INSERT INTO TBL_Stream (Name, Abbrev) VALUES        ('" & row.Cells(0).Value & "','" & row.Cells(1).Value & "')"
                ExecuteSQLQuery(sqlSTR)

                GetGrid()
                MsgBox("Record Saved", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Record")

            End If

        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Yikes, this look scary-vulnerable to sql injection issues!

Comment: This is what happens when you don't do enough reading on a subject. Scrap everything you have there. If you're not already, you should be using a data adapter to retrieve the initial data populate a `DataTable`, then binding that to your grid via a `BindingSource`. When it's time to save changes, a single call to `Update` on the same data adapter is all that's required. Of course, the data adapter needs to be configured to save data, which you can do using a command builder under certain circumstances, or you can create the action commands yourself. Read up on data adapters.

Comment: Before you claim otherwise, there's no reason not to use a data adapter just because you have a dedicated data access layer.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Personally, I'm not a fan of letting adapters write your update queries.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, adapters can't create action commands themselves. You need to use a command builder to do so. I tend not to use command builders myself either, but they will do the job if your query involves a single table with a primary key. Some people are against using such tools on principle but the same people will generally use many other tools to make writing code easier and quicker so, in my opinion, an aversion to command builders is misguided. What do you think the problem is with using one?

Comment: @jmcilhinney This question is actually one good example... you often don't know up front whether you need an insert or an update.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, fair point in this case. I should have read more carefully. Didn't realise that the request was actually for an upsert. If you're retrieving data, editing it and saving the changes then there's no real reason not to use a command builder, other than personal preference. If you're loading data from an external source, which is presumably what's happening here, then a command builder is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

I can't fully answer this, because you didn't show us a way to run an SQL query on your database that correctly handles parameters. The code you have, including the `ExecuteSQL()` method, is **horribly broken**, and will fail any time a name or abbreviation has, for example, a single quote as part of the value.

Of course, you could escape for that... but that's just **one** way of several user input could break your SQL. Worse, malicious users can use this to cause *very bad things* to happen in your database.

So instead, I've written this out showing some good practices, including parameterized queries and an [all-sql upsert](https://michaeljswart.com/2017/07/sql-server-upsert-patterns-and-antipatterns/). You'll have to fill in the connection string and correct column information. Moreover, *you need to adopt this pattern throughout your application!* Yes, that will mean updating the `ExecuteSQL()` method.

**THIS STUFF IS IMPORTANT!**

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim SQL As STring = _
"BEGIN TRY
  INSERT INTO TBL_Stream (Name, Abbrev) VALUES (@Name, @Abbrev);
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  -- ignore duplicate key errors, throw the rest.
  IF ERROR_NUMBER() IN (2601, 2627) 
    UPDATE TBL_Stream
       SET Abbrev = @Abbrev
     WHERE Name = @Name;
END CATCH"

    Using cn As New SqlConnection(" connection string here "), _
          cmd As New SqlCommand(SQL, cn)

        'I have to guess at type and length. You should use the actual type and length from the database
        Dim name As SqlParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50)
        Dim abbrev As SqlParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Abbrev", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10)

        cn.Open()
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
            If Not row.IsNewRow Then
                name.Value = row.Cells(0).Value        
                abbrev.Value = row.Cells(1).Value
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End If
        Next row

    End Using
    GetGrid()
    MsgBox("Record Saved", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Saved")

End Sub
```

Now let's work on updating things to better support this throughout your application.

First, make a new `Module`. We'll move things there so we can enforce all database access goes through our new, safe pattern. Then, we can make our new method **private** within the module, which will further reduce temptation to write bad queries. Finally, each query you need to run will get it's own public method in the Module. Now, accessing your database will look more like calling regular methods.

Here's what I came up with. There are (so far) three members of this module. Take care to note the Public vs Private choices, because those are *important* for achieving all the goals here:

```
Public Module DB

    Private Property ConnectionString As String = " connection string here "

    Private Function ExecuteSQL(SQL As String, Params Parameters() As SqlParameter) As DataTable
        Dim result As New DataTable
        'Because of connection pooling it really is better to create a new connection object in most circumstances.
        'Don't try to reuse the same connection throughout your app!
        Using cn As New SqlConnection(ConnectionString), _
              cmd As New SqlCommand(SQL, cn)

              If Parameters IsNot Nothing Then
                   cmd.Parameters.AddRange(Parameters)
              End If

              cn.Open()
              Using rdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                  result.Load(rdr)
                  Return result
              End Using
        End Using
    End Function

    'This is just one way to build this method. 
    ' The important thing is all methods here are encouraged to use good parameterization
    Public Sub UpsertStream(Name As String, Abbrev As String)
        Dim SQL As STring = _
"BEGIN TRY
  INSERT INTO TBL_Stream (Name, Abbrev) VALUES (@Name, @Abbrev);
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  -- ignore duplicate key errors, throw the rest.
  IF ERROR_NUMBER() IN (2601, 2627) 
    UPDATE TBL_Stream
       SET Abbrev = @Abbrev
     WHERE Name = @Name;
END CATCH"

       Dim n As New SqlParameter("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = Name
       Dim a As New SqlParameter("@Abbrev", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10).Value = Abbrev    
       ExecuteSQL(SQL, n, a)
    End Sub

End Module
```

And here's how to use it with the Button_Click() method:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        If Not row.IsNewRow Then
            DB.UpsertStream(row.Cells(0).Value, row.Cells(1).Value)
        End If
    Next row
    GetGrid()
    MsgBox("Record Saved", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Saved")
End Sub
```

As the application grows, you could eventually move this module to it's own class library project, where the Module and the `ExecuteSQL()` method as declared as `Friend` instead of Public or Private. Then you can also move the numerous Public methods into other new Public Modules within that class library, to get logical groupings between feature areas.

Comment: How about a datatype for ExecuteSQL.

Comment: Actually, a DataTable doesn't seen to make much sense for an upsert but I guess it is generic so it could be used for a Select too. Yes?

Comment: I don't believe the line continuation character is necessary when combining 2 objects in a Using block.

Comment: The sql string is interesting. I have used `If Exists`... for this purpose. In .net I have been told not to use error handling to trap avoidable errors but I guess Sql Server must have  less cumbersome exception handling.

Comment: @Mary, Yes, the idea is to be generic, but I should have had the `As DataTable` at the end (that's what I get for typing direct into the reply window, fixed now). Also, there are a few exceptions to the "No exceptions" rule, even in .Net. For example, it's better to handle the exception than to check `File.Exists()`. There's a link in the post explaning the various upsert pattern options.

Comment: That link is quite an article. What I don't know about Sql Server could fill the Astrodome but it did advance my knowledge  even with my limits. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't read the question carefully enough to begin with but you can still perform upserts with a data adapter and `DataTable`.  You just start with an empty `DataTable`, add all the desired rows and then call `Update` on a data adapter with appropriate upsert SQL in the `InsertCommand`, e.g.

```
Private adapter As SqlDataAdapter
Private table As DataTable

Private Sub ConfigureDataAccess()
    Dim connection As New SqlConnection("Server=(local);Database=Test;Trusted_Connection=True;")

    adapter = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Table_1", connection)

    Dim upsertSql = "
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table_1 WHERE Id = @Id)
    UPDATE Table_1 SET Name = @Name WHERE Id = @Id
ELSE
    INSERT INTO Table_1 (Name) VALUES (@Name)"
    Dim upsertCommand As New SqlCommand(upsertSql, connection)

    upsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "Id")
    upsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "Name")

    adapter.InsertCommand = upsertCommand
    table = New DataTable()
End Sub

Private Sub GetSchema()
    adapter.FillSchema(table, SchemaType.Source)
    BindingSource1.DataSource = table
    DataGridView1.DataSource = BindingSource1
End Sub

Private Sub SaveData()
    Validate()
    BindingSource1.EndEdit()
    adapter.Update(table)
End Sub
```

The SQL for the insert and update goes in the `InsertCommand` because all the `DataRows` in the `DataTable` will have a `RowState` of `Added`, so the `InsertCommand` will be executed for each one. In this example, I have called `FillSchema` to create a `DataTable` with a schema that matches the database but with no rows. You can create your `DataTable` however is appropriate.